# Supervisor requires reload for flask application to work properly

Tags: python, supervisord, gunicorn, flask

When my server (centOS 7 hosted on a vagrant VM) reboots, my Python Flask application (served up by Gunicorn using nginx as a reverse proxy) throws internal server errors (according to the stack traces I'm getting, it can't find templated html files even...) until a `sudo supervisorctl reload` is issued.  After this, the application runs just fine and my life is good but that won't do now will it?

I suspect a race condition (maybe between supervisor and gunicorn?).  I tried adding a sleep to the `command` in the specific program's `.ini` file but this didn't help anything.

Has anyone else encountered something like this?  If not, does anyone know of how to delay the start of the entire supervisor utility (not just one specific program)?

For reference, here's what the contents of my `.ini` file look like:

```
[program:test]
command=/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 2 the_app:app
directory=/var/www/test
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Again, this works fine after supervisor is reloaded it just doesn't seem to start up correctly (presumably because of some kind of race condition).

For completeness:  the addition of the sleep condition caused the `.ini` file to look like:

```
[program:test]
command=bash -c "sleep 10 && exec /bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 2 the_app:app"
directory=/var/www/test
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Aside from not fixing the problem (lol), this feels dirty so I strongly prefer not to do something like this.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Why have you used supervisord instead of [normal systemd units](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am entertaining the idea of using supervisord based on wanting to experiment with some of the monitoring/dashboard tools built for supervisord: http://supervisord.org/plugins.html but so far this issue is pushing me back towards systemd